# How to add a incrementing number sequence to informatica target flat file everytime its created

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have been really trying hard to find a solution for this but i am having no luck. I am new to informatica and I have created a mapping in informatica with a target flat file. My target flat file name is `Startup_YYMMDD_XXX.csv`. The `xxx` represents the sequence number every time a file is created. For example if i run the mapping first time it should be 001, second time 002 and so on. Can someone please help me out?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Create a persistent workflow variable and increase the same in your mapping whenever it runs. Store the value back to the repository. Use it to name the file using FileName port in the target

Comment: Take a look at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Tried that didnt work. I was hoping if i use a sequence generator and get a solution from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stg file or a DB table too to store last run_id and then increase this by 1 for every run.Here are more details -

1. In the target definition, add a FileName port.
2. Do a lookup into the stg file/DB table to fetch the latest run_id. Use any dummy column as lookup condition. Make sure this data type is NUMBER.
3. Next use run_id+1 to generate next run_id. create a output port to generate name with run_id-
   `out_FileName = 'Startup_'|| TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYMMDD')||'_'|| LPAD(IIF(ISNULL(latest_run_id),0,latest_run_id) +1,3,'0')||'.csv'`
4. Link above out_FileName port to target file name in target and generate the target.
5. Store latest_run_id+1 in the same stg file.

But most of ETL systems tracks this run IDs through some tool. You can use those tool generated IDs too.